# how to upload video/data to server via xhr request? via JS

Tags: javascript, html, video, upload

I'm trying to work on a site to upload video clips for myself and a close group of friends.

I'm using HFS as a home server for now to test things.

My issue is whenever I drag & drop my video all that happens is the url switches from my ip to the folder destination.  i.e.  192.168/asd/ to c:/users/etc.mp4

I think the issue is the xhr request, I'm trying to get it to go to a folder I've designated but it doesn't seem to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. I'm not the best coder obviously but I'm also not plagiarizing anything, I found bits and pieces of this off of a guide online at github.

```
function readfiles(files) {
debugger;
var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (tests.formdata) formData.append('file', files[i]);
  previewfile(files[i]);
}

// now post a new XHR request
if (tests.formdata) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'my server url here?' );
  xhr.onload = function() {
    progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
  };

  if (tests.progress) {
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
        progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

}

Comment: You do have code to handle the drag/drop event, right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm using except I've slightly modified to code:

http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

I'm trying to get it to upload to a file on my server and then play the video with a new URL that my friends can link to each other...

Comment: Well that's the code that isn't working - the DND code - not the upload code. When you dragged the video over and the browser loaded it, it means you weren't handling the DND right.